# Why iCloud for Windows 10 is not working?

Tags: icloud, windows

I downloaded the latest iCloud software for Windows 10. It installed but is not working properly. It is not downloading the photos from the iCloud.

Is there any way to ensure that the photos are downloaded to the local PC desktop? (I tried Download Photos but it is still not downloading.)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working properly"?  Depending on how many photos you have, and their size, it could take a few days for iCloud to sync on your Windows machine.  Please [edit] your question to include the steps you've taken and any error messages you've received.

Comment: I am pretty clear. The pictures are not downloading even after a week. There were no error messages. I installed , I clicked on download photos , it didn’t work. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of all, I would like to answer the question. Yesterday I uninstalled the icloud for windows 10 and then reinstalled it from Microsoft store. To my surprise it started working after 10-12 hours as I clicked on Download Photos , it asked me which photos to download.